# CREATE TABLE once but INSERT INTO twice

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried repeatedly to use a combination of "CREATE TABLE" and "ALTER TABLE...ADD" and "UPDATE..SET...WHERE" to produce an online survey which has two parts. Part one you add some user input and part two is just the same -- you input some values. It has become clear to me that, for whatever reason, when I use the above combination of SQL statements, the user input from the second portion of the questionnaire does NOT get fed into MySQL. The fields for the second part of the survey remain BLANK. I have literally tried it dozens of times. Failing everything else, I decided to CREATE TABLE with ALL the input text fields (in other words, I did not just the use the text fields from the first portion and then use ALTER TABLE to add columns from the second portion -- no -- as I mentioned, this does NOT work). What I tried instead was, on my first PHP file, I had:

```
   $sql = "CREATE TABLE hollywoodmovies (ID INT(10), Year INT(10), 
           LeadActor VARCHAR(60), StudioName VARCHAR(20), PRIMARY KEY(ID))";
```

And then the second PHP file deals with the online survey part one:

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO hollywoodmovies (ID, Year, LeadActor, StudioName)
           VALUES ('$uniqueid', '$year', '$actorname', '$studiolist')";
```

This is despite the fact that online survey part one has only two form fields: ID and YEAR

Now, the second portion of the survey, I did EXACTLY the same as the above:

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO hollywoodmovies (ID, Year, LeadActor, StudioName)
           VALUES ('$uniqueid', '$year', '$actorname', '$studiolist')";
```

And this is despite the fact that I again have only two form fields for the second portion of the questionnaire/survey: LEADACTOR and STUDIONAME.

What is happening at run-time is that ALL desired fields ARE being allocated their respective values -- unlike when I used ALTER TABLE and UPDATE, at which time the input from the second portion of the survey went missing. So this is good -- up to a point. What is happening, however, is that I am getting TWO records (rows), not one. In the first record, the first two columns have user input appearing in them, but the last two are blank. And in the second row, the first two columns are blank, but the last two columns have data. Is there ANY way I can have just one record, and not two? (Would it be possible to use the word NULL somewhere to make the blanks disappear, giving me just one record?) Remember, my particular SQL server is VERY troublesome -- I cannot use ALTER or UPDATE or whatever else because my server just doesn't like it. I can only use CREATE in combination with "INSERT INTO...VALUES". Ay ideas, please?

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT` will certainly create 2 rows, especially if you don't have a PK restraing on the ID column and are using that in both INSERT statements.

on your second statement to populate LEADACTOR and STUDIONAME do an `UPDATE`

e.g. `UPDATE hollywoodmovies SET StudioName = $studioname, LeadActor = $leadactor WHERE ID = $uniqueid`